# Commands from File Menu missing in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

The File Menu in ArcMap 10.2.2 is suddenly missing a whole bunch of commands, including Export Map. Anyone knows why, and how I can restore the File Menu?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this [ESRI thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/78531) might help.

Answer (score 6):

Many issues with ArcMap, particularly UI-related issues can be fixed by renaming your Normal.mxt file. It can be found in the %APPDATA%\Esri\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates folder.

More details here:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00v000000014000000

(Renaming is preferable to deleting the file, so you can roll back the changes if you need.)